# Multiple sensors on one GPIO

Tags: gpio, electronics

I would like to know is it possible to connect for example: thermometer and pressure sensor to one GPIO?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: it depends.

If you are dealing with 1-wire bus sensors, which are digital and can understand individual addressing, it is perfectly possible.

Just stack up to 10 of them in the 1-wire GPIO pin (check [adafruit's tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/overview) on how to connect one and repeat for up to 10 in the same pin). This works, I have a configuration with 2 DS18B20 working perfectly.

The i2c protocol is also addressed, and should support connecting more than one device likewise. I haven't personally tested the implementation used on the Pi to be sure.

Other sensors/protocols might not understand addressing and just might not work.

Comment: I2C certainly works on the Pi.  It needs two gpios, for data and clock (and a ground connection).  You can connect as many devices as can be uniquely addressed (112 for the Pi's 7 bit addressing).  I've only had four connected at once.